# how to listview rows should be clickable?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

1. How to set sqlite table-data to list-view in android?
2. Moreover, how to allow list of rows to be clickable?

   ```
       ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listlayout,R.id.label , mobileArray);

       ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mobile_list);
       listView.setAdapter(adapter);
   ```

Comment: 1. Too broad; 2. set OnItemClickListener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int position, long id) {
          //your code
        }

    });
```

Comment: thanks I got it but right now I want to get the id of the clicked row : the row data - will be the data of the sqlIte table